# Is "I wish to" more peremptory than "I would like to"?

Tags: tone

Would you say that "I wish" carries some sort of peremptory tone, or none at all?  The difference being in the context of a presentation:

"I wish to introduce an idea" *vs*. "I would like to introduce an idea".

Which one would carry less hesitation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "I wish to" *may*, depending on context, sound more curt, demanding and businesslike (in a word, *peremptory*) than "I would like to".

Consider:

"*I wish to* lodge a complaint."

against

"*I would like to* lodge a complaint."

Which sounds more natural? I think the first sounds a lot more natural to me. Since lodging a complaint is decidedly not a nicety, the phrase that goes with it is more fitting in the context of a demand or curt request.

However, in a more neutral or positive context (such as making a commendation) neither phrase comes across as more demanding, and both phrases would be appropriate. So it's not an absolute distinction.

Comment: You're still several degrees away from peremptory. "I wish to" and "I would like to" are considered, where I come from, rather formal and reserved, not at all demanding. Demanding would be "I have a complaint!" or "I have a bone to pick with you!" or "Put down that phone and talk to me *now*!"

Comment: @Robusto The examples you gave would not be considered professional in a formal business context. Many formal business and diplomatic communications are carried out behind the (admittedly hypocritical) veil of a studied courtesy. In that sort of setting, if disapproval or an objection needs to be raised, then "I wish to" sounds better. Now as to whether this is *peremptory* is subjective; however since a fairly forceful demand may be hiding behind these formal niceties, I don't think the adjective is misplaced.

Comment: . . . "may be hiding"? Doesn't sound at all peremptory to me. Anyway, that's all I have to say on the subject, since we are unlikely to find common ground here.

Comment: I think what's at the heart of this isn't the possibility of a distinction based on ***wish/like***. It's the difference between, say, *I ask you to reconsider* and *I **would** ask you to reconsider*. Where in general the "modalized" version is more circumspect/deferential (figuratively, the implication is I'm not *actually* asking you, but I *would* if you were to ***allow me to***, for example).